# Updating object in memory when Activity is stopped

Tags: android

Just curious how people are handling this situation:

Let's say when your Activity is created you launch an AsyncTask or Thread to hit a web service and retrieve a piece of data.  Suppose, before the AsyncTask finishes, the user has hit some button that sends them to a new Activity.  While on the new Activity, the AsyncTask finishes.

When the AsyncTask finishes, you want a member variable of the first Activity to update, but that Activity is now stopped.

What do you do?  As I understand it, you can't safely access the member variable because Android could have reclaimed it.  You could use a BroadcastReceiver, but if you're no longer on that Activity, the BR won't receive the message.  So what is the right answer?

Update:

A possibility is to have the task write to a database and read from that database in the Activity's onResume().  However, in my case, this is not appropriate.  The data in my Activity is not to be written (read: saved) to the database until the user is finished with that Activity and has clicked a "save" button.

Comment: Perhaps using a service that keeps the state. Your first activity would (if running) query the service periodically for it's state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I understand it, you can't safely
>   access the member variable because
>   Android could have reclaimed it.

Nope, as long as you have a reference to an object (including `Activity` instances) then it still exists. Your first `Activity` still exists while it is in the stopped state... it is fine for your `AsyncTask` to update UI elements or any associated data.

It is however possible for your `Activity` to be permanently removed from your task while your `AsyncTask` is running... perhaps this is what you were thinking of?

The most common case is when the user simply changes the orientation of the phone. Your activity will likely be destroyed and recreated anew. If you have data which needs to survive this - it's likely that you do - then implement [`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) and call `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` from `onCreate()` to handle this. (Obviously your `AsyncTask` that's running through all of this should know to update things on the later instance, not the previous one).

Finally, if your AsyncTask does update UI (as seems likely) then it's better for it to keep `WeakReferences` on UI objects rather than direct references. Activities are expensive objects, and as long as something's keeping a reference to one (and every View contains a reference to it's owning Context/Activity), it can't be GC'd. Very easy to leak memory that way.

Comment: Currently, my AsyncTask updates a member variable and then calls a Runnable to execute a method that shows the member variable's contents in a TextView.  Would you be able to provide me with a link to an example of a correct implementation of onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() to help mull it over?

Comment: Why do that business with the Runnable? The whole benefit of AsyncTask is that onPostExecute() runs on the UI thread... no runnable required.

Comment: Re onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(), the simplest (laziest!) thing to do is simply "return this;". Then in onCreate() you do "MyActivity prev = (MyActivity)getLastNonConfigurationActivity(); if (prev != null) { this.foo = prev.foo; this.bar = prev.bar; ... etc ... }".

Comment: Ahh! Sounds simple enough. Using a Runnable is a remnant of moving Thread objects over to AsyncTask objects :P  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Intents to send the result to the Activity who started the AsyncTask (you can do that in `onPostExecute` method), the OS will bring it to front or will re-launch it if it is stopped.

Then in your activity `onCreate` you have to make a `getIntent` and check if it has the result, also you need to implement `onNewIntent` callback so you are notified if your Activity is currently running an receives the Intent with the data, you have to call `getIntent` also in this callback.